# Как правильно использовать функцию ExecuteAsyncScript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

У меня есть тест, который проверяет работоспособность всех страниц. Решил сделать это с помощью fetch. Для каждой страницы вызываю:

`Driver.HandleXHR(link);`

```
public static void HandleXHR(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
{
    var js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
    dynamic response = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(
            "const result = await fetch(arguments[0]);" +
            "console.log(result);" +
            "return result;", url);
    Assert.IsTrue((bool)response["ok"], $"{response["status"]}, {response["url"]}");
}
```

Проблема такая: на первой итерации при завершении выполнения скрипта выбрасывается `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : script timeout`.

Вопрос: Как мне переписать мой скрипт js, чтобы это сработало для `ExecuteAsyncScript()`?

Comment: Если я изменю `dynamic response = js.ExecuteAsyncScript` => `dynamic response = js.ExecuteScript` всё заработает... Хотелось бы узнать, почему нельзя использовать Async

Answer (score 0):

В общем насколько я понял вернуть результат можно вызвав `callback()`, а в качестве параметра - то что хотите вернуть.

Вот реализация через `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
public static void HandleXHR(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
{
    var js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
    dynamic response = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(
        "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
         "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
         $"xhr.open('GET', '{url}', true);" +
         "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
         "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
         "    callback(xhr);" +
         "  }" +
         "};" +
         "xhr.send();");
    Assert.AreEqual(200, response["status"], $"{response["status"]}, {response["statusText"]}, {response["responseURL"]}");
}
```

Вот реализация через `fetch()`:

```
public static void HandleXHR(this IWebDriver driver, string url)
{
    var js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
    dynamic response = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(
            "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
            $"callback(await fetch('{url}'));");
    Assert.IsTrue((bool)response["ok"], $"{response["status"]}, {response["url"]}");
}
```

PS Лично у меня через `fetch()` выполняется быстрее на 2.5 сек. 56 страниц.